# How to type MUI Typography props? v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I understand what I need to do, get the type definition for `Typography.variant` However I am not sure how to get these really.

```
interface TextProps {
  variant?: string
  component?: string
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void
}

export const Text = ({ children, variant = 'body1', component = 'body1', onClick }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  return (
    <Typography variant={variant} component={component} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Typography>
  )
}
```

### TS Error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<TypographyTypeMap<{}, "span">>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "caption" | "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6" | "inherit" | "overline" | "body1" | "subtitle1" | "subtitle2" | "body2" | undefined'.  TS2769
```

Comment: `OverridableStringUnion<Variant | 'inherit', TypographyPropsVariantOverrides>` Seems to fix it for variant, but not for component

Comment: I don't think `component = 'body1'` is valid, maybe something like `component = 'span'`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this is how you can fix the type errors, both `variant` and `component` are not string, you can look at the `Typography` type definition file [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Typography/Typography.d.ts) for reference.

```
import Typography, { TypographyTypeMap } from "@mui/material/Typography";

interface TextProps {
  variant?: TypographyTypeMap["props"]["variant"];
  component?: React.ElementType;
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void;
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Well well! lol I clearly need to improve my understanding. With TS I guess it is just assumed that you need to look at the type definitions of packages to get things playing nicely?

Comment: @JamieHutber yeah, most of the time I just look at the type definition, but third-party library type can look intimidating so it took me a while to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and I could fix by this way. Basing in on your code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Variant } from '@mui/material/styles/createTypography';

interface TextProps {
variant?: Variant
component?: React.ElementType
onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void
  }


export const Text = ({ children, variant = 'body1', component = 'body1', onClick }: PropsWithChildren<TextProps>) => {
  return (
    <Typography variant={variant} component={component} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Typography>
  )

}
```

There is another casting to the concerning element using 'as'. Eg:

```
    <Typography variant={variant as Variant } component={component as React.ElementType } onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
    </Typography>
```

This way is most used when are used flat objects, but in your case that you've used an interface the best practice is to define their properties types into the interface.

Thumbs up!